# Add imageview programmatically constraints problem

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I'm building an app (for `Android`) using `Android Studio` and I'm facing some troubles regarding the position of a programmatically added `ImageView` to my `FrameLayout`.

First things first: I have an initial `ImageView` on that `FrameLayout` called `AVATAR01` as you can see on the `xml` file:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayJog"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/AVATAR01"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar01" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then I use the next `JAVA` piece of code to add another `ImageView` similar to the one I already declared before:

```
//Objects:
    ImageView IMG01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.AVATAR01);
    FrameLayout LAYJOG = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayJog);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams LAYPAR = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(IMG01.getLayoutParams());
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams MARPAR = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(IMG01.getLayoutParams());
//New ImageView:
    ImageView IMG02 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    IMG02.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LAYPAR));
    IMG02.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(MARPAR));
    IMG02.setTop(100);
    IMG02.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar02);
    LAYJOG.addView(IMG02);
```

The code above doesn't has any `runtime errors`, but the program places the new image at position `(0, 0)` of the `FrameLayout`. I'm pretty sure this is something to do with the constraints settings of the new `ImageView` I added, but I'm not able to fix this. Does anyone knows how can I place the new `ImageView` at position `(10, 100)`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem by adding margin to ImageView.
for example :

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

    ImageView IMG02 = new ImageView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(LEFT , TOP , RIGHT , BOTTOM);
    IMG02.setLayoutParams(layoutParams;

    layout.addView(IMG02);
```

you must insert your value instead of "LEFT , TOP , RIGHT , BOTTOM"

Comment: Thanks! I used `layoutParams.setTop` instead but it's the same concept! So simple.. ;)